# Count Distinct Values in the entire sheets

Tags: excel, pivot-table

May I know any ways can provide the required result?
I tried using pivot table, but found some wordings cannot be showed.
Result table should show the unique count of item name in 20 cols x 150,000 rows.

## DATA

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | .... | Col20 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| coffee | tea | bread | n/a | ... | n/a |
| bread | ice cream | n/a | n/a | ... | n/a |
| mango juice | bread | coke | wine | ... | ice cream |
| coke | cake | ice cream | n/a | ... | n/a |
| wine | bread | coke | n/a | ... | n/a |
| {below about 150,000 records} | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

## RESULT

| ItemName | Qty |
| --- | --- |
| bread | 40000 |
| coffee | 90000 |
| coke | 5000 |
| .... | .... |
| .... | .... |
| .... | .... |
| .... | .... |
| wine | 2000 |

Comment: I do not see the column "quantity".  Where is it?

Comment: @OzgunSenyuva the qty is count result of ItemName in the whole sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I seperated the data into 10 parts.
The function worked normal for each parts of data.
Afterwards, I merge the results together and count the total.

Reason for the incorrect pivot output: data is too many to handle by excel

Answer (score 1):

If you have ***Excel-365*** then you may try below formulas.

```
G2=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,A2:E6)&"</s></t>","//s")))

H2=COUNTIF(A2:E6,G2#)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but i dont know is it bcoz of my data is too big to process.  It return me "#CALC!" if selected range higher than 2347.        <br/>  

NORMAL sorting result by:   
   <br/>  
=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE, **A2:H2347** )&"</s></t>","//s")))       
  <br/>  
FAIL by:   
  <br/>  
=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE, **A2:H2348** )&"</s></t>","//s")))

Comment: `FILTERXML` has a string length ,imit, which with 150,000 x 20 cells you will exceed many times over

Comment: @chrisneilsen
 then the best way is to seperate the data before sorting. thousand thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

Insert a Pivot table and select the option "Add this data to the Data Model"

[image]

and then from "Value Field Settings" for the column in the Values area select "Distinct Count"

[image]

Comment: Yea, I used it at first, but found a lot of items cannot be listed in the pivot table. I dont know if there is any data limitation?

Comment: There is abt 150,000 rows in 20 cols for the data

Answer (score 1):

To get unique list you can use:

```
=LET(data,$A$2:$E$10000, 
     rows, A1:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(data),0),
     SORT(
      UNIQUE(
        INDEX(data,
              1+INT((ROW(rows)-1)/COLUMNS(data)),
              MOD(ROW(rows)-1+COLUMNS(data),
              COLUMNS(data))+1)
       )
     )
   )
```

and to get count:

```
=COUNTIF(A2:E10000,H2#)
```

[image]